# How to compare array string value with enum values

Tags: java, arrays, string, enums

Here i would like to know how to equate the array values to the enum values irrespective to the lowercase and upper case.

```
enum Color{ RED, BLACK, WHITE, PINK}

public static void main{
  Scanner keyboard  = new Scanner(System.in);
  String input = keyboard next Line();
  String[] array = input.split(" ");
  for(int i=0; i<=array.length; i++){
     if("How to equate the array values to the enum values irrespective to the lowercase and upper case") 
      {
        System.out.print(array[i] + "is in the enum values");
      }
  }
}
```

User input:

```
orange red purple
```

Output should be:

```
red is in the enum values
```

Comment: What about something like `if (array[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Color.RED.toString()))`? As an alternative, you could extend the `enum` by specific `String` values, but it won't stay a one-liner then...

Comment: @deHaar i would suggest `name()` instead of `toString()`, but it works

Comment: @f1sh thanks, better use `name()`, right...

Comment: @f1sh from Enum::name javadocs: Most programmers should use the toString() method in preference to this one, as the toString method may return a more user-friendly name.

Comment: @Mr.Robot yes, but exactly that is the issue here. You don't want to compare `"RED"` with a "more user-friendly name" or whatever a possible overridden `toString()` returns, but you want to compare it to the enum constant name, which is exactly what `name()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `name()` method of enum.

in if condition you can use this condition.

`array[i].toUpperCase().equals(Color.RED.name())`

If you want to iterate over enum values then you can use `values()`.

```
for(String color: Color.values()){
    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pick them all by lambda by one line :

```
List<String> wanted = Arrays.stream(Color.values())
.filter(color->Arrays.asList(array).contains(color.name()))
.map(Color::name).collect(Collectors.asList());
```

or just print them

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(Color.values())
.filter(color -> Arrays.asList(array).contains(color.name()))
.map(Color::name).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use with this :

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

           Scanner keyboard  = new Scanner(System.in);
           String input = keyboard.nextLine();
           String[] array = input.split(" ");
           for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
              if(array[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Color.RED.name()) || 
                      array[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Color.BLACK.name()) ||
                      array[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Color.WHITE.name()) ||
                      array[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Color.PINK.name())) {
                 System.out.print(array[i] + "is in the enum values");
               }

     }



           }
        enum Color{ RED, BLACK, WHITE, PINK};
         }
```

Also you hava a problem with   `for(int i=0; i<=array.length; i++)` you need to change it to `i<array.length` , beacuse it give a error of `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` .

**Output :**

```
orange red purple
red is in the enum values

orange purple black
black is in the enum values

white hello world
white is in the enum values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an enumeration class to do the compare job.

```
public enum Color {
//red
RED("red"),
//black
BLACK("black"),
//white
WHITE("white"),
//pink
PINK("pink");

private String desc;

Color(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public static boolean isExist(String color) {
    for (Color c : Color.values()) {
        if (c.desc.compareTo(color) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}}
```

The below is the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();
    String[] array = input.split(" ");
    for (String s : array) {
        if (Color.isExist(s.toLowerCase())) {
            System.out.print(s + " is in the enum values");
        }
    }
}
```

ps:

```
for (int i=0; i<=array.length; i++) {}
```

It will throw java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.You can write the two below methods.

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length;i++) {}
or    
for (String s : array) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution using [`String#join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) and `Stream` API:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

enum Color {
    RED, BLACK, WHITE, PINK
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        String values = String.join("", Stream.of(Color.values()).map(c -> c.name()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        for (String s : input.split("\\s+")) {
            if (values.contains(s.toUpperCase())) {
                System.out.print(s + " is in the enum values");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
orange red purple
red is in the enum values
```